# Replacing a SVN controlled file with a local file using copy and paste

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have some files in source control under SVN. If I replace these files with local, non-source controlled files using windows copy + paste, how will SVN handle the update? Will the files just be replaced 100% with the local version of the file? Or will SVN see it as a merge-style operation?

The icon overlay appears with the red question mark when I copy and paste, so I am wondering how it handles it when I commit?

Thanks

Ronan

Comment: There's less magic involved than you thin. All Subversion does it to compare file contents. How contents got there is irrelevant.

Comment: So if line 1 of an SVN controlled file called test.txt contains the string "SVN-controlled". And I replace it by using Windows copy and paste with a non-SVN controlled document also called test.txt that has a blank line 1, and a line 2 containing the string "local-file". What will the updated file look like? Will it contain the content on both line 1 and line 2? Or will it contain exactly what is in the pasted file: blank line 1 and "local-file" on line 2?

Comment: Subversion does not interfere with your disk I/O operations. File contents will be identical either using Subversion or not.